# Login to oauth dialog from facebook with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, facebook, puppeteer

I'm trying to interface a website, and one of the ways you can log on there is by using a Facebook login (it opens a pop-up, you can enter username/password or simply confirm if you're already logged on, you know the drill...).

Well, I'm trying to interface it with Puppeteer, and the strange thing is that I don't get the page. I mean, I'm working in non-headless mode so I can **SEE** the popup, it just looks like Puppeteer can't see it...

A lot of pages said to try something like this:

```
const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.once('targetcreated', target => x(target.page()))); 
await page.click('<some selector>');
const popup = await newPagePromise;
```

But this doesn't give me a "popup" I can use (`popup: null`). I also tried to make it wait for 10s, but no luck then either...

When looking at all_pages: `let all_pages = await browser.pages();`, this array has 1 page. My original page... No Facebook popup. (But it is displayed on my screen!)

What am I missing here? How can I get this information in my automation process?
BTW: the Facebook popup also has 'Chrome is being controlled by automated test software.'. So I would assume I can reach this information somehow.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: you need to use the graph api instead...what you want to do is not allowed on facebook.

Comment: On the same site, there is also a google login button. It seems that I'm also not getting that popup there. Is Google also forbidding to interface its site with automated software?

Comment: not sure about google, but i would assume so. you should never create any software that asks for passwords of users. everyone should use 2FA anyway, which is available for both platforms. why not just use the official ways? google and facebook both offer apis for login.

Comment: @luschn What I'm trying to do is not login to facebook, but more like login to stack overflow through facebook. You know you have that login button when you try to login? This is completely seperated from 2FA. 2FA is an additional security measure beside a U/P request. Why not use the official ways: because how can I pass the access tokens from the API to the call for the login to stackoverflow? That would just be adding more complexity... And it would be much simpler to follow the user-oriented flow.

Comment: what is the use case for this? users can just use stackoverflow directly and login there. what you want to achieve sounds like something highly illegal, to be honest. i know what 2FA is, i just meant that you would have to register puppeteer with 2FA if the user activated it, which is impossible, i guess.

Comment: I'm not logging into SO, but a 3rd party website. I don't have 2FA activated on that site, and it's just for personal use. I want to interface with the site in an automated manner. How I did now was login through Facebook manually, and the site stores a cookie on my puppeteer. I save all the cookies and load it in my browser next time. Works fine, but I would like to have that automated if I ever were logged out. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

`browser` is used to connect with Chromium, it is only called at the beggining. The same way you interact with the main page using `const page = await browser.newPage()`,
you have to use that same variable once the popup emerges as well, on the other hand,`'targetcreated'` is not the event you are looking for but `'popup'`. Have in mind that `page` provides methods to interact with tabs, therefore, updating the code:

```
const newPagePromise = new Promise(event => page.once('popup', event));
```

This can be found in puppeteer documentation:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.2.1/docs/api.md#event-popup